# How to call firebase cloud function after a updated value in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function, which triggers when a value is updated. Say, If an order is delivered and it's status is marked as delivered in firestore, i need the function to execute after 15 minutes whicn sends notification to the user.

```
exports.notificationOnDelivered = functions.firestore
    .document('orders/{orderId}')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const after = change.after.data();
        if (after.status === 'Delivered') {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                const notification = new OneSignal.Notification();
                notification.app_id = ONESIGNAL_APP_ID;
                notification.include_player_ids = [after.uid.fcm_token];
                notification.contents = {
                    en: "Rate your Order"
                };
                notification.headings = {
                    en: "Go to -> My orders -> Rate now to rate your order"
                  }
                await client.createNotification(notification);
            }, 900000)
        }
    })
```

Currently, i'm using settimeout. But after some SO answers, i came to know that using settimeout is not appropriate. What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> I need the function to execute after 15 minutes which sends
> notification to the user... What's the right way of doing this?

A correct approach to do that is described in this article: [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

This approach is based on Cloud Tasks and on two Cloud Functions:

- One Cloud Function to trigger when the `order` document is updated (i.e. the Cloud Function you already wrote but that needs to be adapted) and which schedules a task;
- Another Cloud Function, of type HTTPS, for Cloud Tasks to invoke when it’s time for it to send the notification (i.e. 15 minutes later). It's in this CF that you'll send the notifcation.

Comment: Hello @AzhagappanKathiresan, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?